# AWS Lambda with RDS Postgresql - Unknown Issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have been wrestling with this issue for 3 days now and cannot figure out what's wrong.  I set all my login credentials as environment variables in my Lambda function.  My RDS instance is open to publics and security groups also opens the ports for incoming and outgoing.

my PostgresQL code went to a tons of variations, the latest one is from this [AWS Lambda NodeJS Connect to RDS Postgres Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982115/aws-lambda-nodejs-connect-to-rds-postgres-database)

my current lambda code

```
const pg = require('pg')
const pool = new pg.Pool()

async function query (q) {
  const client = await pool.connect()
  let res
  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')
    try {
      res = await client.query(q)
      await client.query('COMMIT')
    } catch (err) {
      await client.query('ROLLBACK')
      throw err
    }
  } finally {
    client.release()
  }
  return res
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
      const { rows } = await query("select 'thaison' as ")
      console.log(JSON.stringify(rows[0]))
      var response = {
          "statusCode": 200,
          "headers": {
              "Content-Type" : "application/json"
          },
          "body": JSON.stringify(rows),
          "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Database ' + err)
      callback(null, 'Database ' + err);
    }
};
```

I can successfully do a `console.log` before and after `pool.connect()`.  I can also `console.log` before `client.query()` but not after.  The problem is after `client.query()`, nothing is happening.  I checked Cloudwatch logs and metrics, nothing is on the logs and nothing is reported as errors.  The code must be failing somewhere but I cannot figure out where.  The response is null and I cannot get anything to log after the query, not even in the `catch(err)` block.  The last thing I did was changed the PG endpoint to something that does not even exist, and I am still not getting any errors.  This thing just silently fail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing all the try-catch and simply letting the lambda run fail? This might help you identify the faulty statement. After which you can add back your error handling blocks.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is network-related? Is your Lambda function connected to the same VPC as the RDS database? Is the RDS database configured as `Publicly Available = Yes`? What is the exact configuration of the Inbound Security Group rules?

Comment: @RaghavGarg tried that, not getting any errors but still returns null and cannot console.log anything after the query.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, public available = yes, i even added the VPC and all the private subnet to the lambda function

Comment: Can you please try with a correct SQL query? Something like `select * from pg_tables`, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `Publicly Available = Yes`, the DNS Name of the database will resolve to a **public IP address**. This means that the Lambda function **requires Internet access**.

This can be done by either *NOT* attaching the Lambda function to the VPC, or by attaching the Lambda function to a **private subnet** and then using a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet to provide access to the Internet. The Security Group should permit access from `0.0.0.0/0` (which is very bad for security).

The more 'secure' way to configure such a system would be:

- Use `Publicly Available = No`, which will only resolve the DNS Name of the RDS database to a **private IP address**
- Attach the Lambda function to a subnet in the same VPC as the RDS database
- Attach a Security Group to the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) that permits default "Allow All" outbound access
- Attach a Security Group to the RDS database (`RDS-SG`) that permits Inbound access on port 5432 (PostgreSQL) with `Source = Lambda-SG`

That is, the `RDS-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG` in its Inbound rules. This will permit the Lambda function to access the RDS database.

However, please note that the RDS database will only be accessible from within the VPC. You will not be able to connect to it from your own computer on the Internet (because it is more secure now). You can use a *jump box* with Port Forwarding to connect if desired.

Comment: thanks, I don't see any options to add a security group to a lambda function, can you point me to where it may be? Also, does make it private prevents you from accessing it with pg-admin?

Comment: You can only attach a Security Group if the Lambda function is attached to a VPC. It is in the 'VPC' configuration panel. If the RDS database is set to `Publicly Accessible = No` then you cannot connect to it from the Internet. You would need to go via a Bastion/Jump Box server. Inconvenient? Yes. More secure? Definitely. The choice yours.

Comment: i have to give this a try, my current RDS database is being used by others for different apps such as Smartsheet and QuickSheet which require it to be open to the public.

Comment: In that case, please follow the suggestions at the top of my Answer -- easiest option is to detach the Lambda function from the VPC. This will connect it directly to the Internet, which will give it access to the public IP address of the RDS database.

Comment: I can confirmed that removing VPC, i'm still getting the exact same results.  Regarding the private subnets with the NAT, I'm following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcRKdEP94jM, will update with results.  I'm starting to wonder if the pg library is just not working with Lambda.  Thoughts?

Comment: You could try the code outside of an AWS Lambda function to confirm that it is working. I presume that you have code somewhere that tells it the database connection details, since it isn't shown in your code above.